# Usage of indicator functions as features in Sequential Models

Tags: mallet, crf

I am currently using Mallet for training a sequential model using CRF. I have understood how to provide features (that solely depend on input sequence) to the mallet package. Based on my understanding, in mallet, we have to compute all the values of the feature functions (upfront). Now, I would like to use indicator functions that depend on the label of a token. The value of these functions depends on the output label sequence and during training, I can compute the values of these indicator functions as the output label sequence is known. But, when I am applying this trained CRF model on a new input (whose output label sequene is unknown), how should I calculate the values for such features.

It will be very helpful to me if anyone can provide me any tips/relevant documents.

Answer (score 0):

As you've phrased it, the question doesn't make sense: if you don't know the hidden labels, you can't set anything based on those unknown labels. An example might help.

You may not need to explicitly record these relationships. At training time the algorithm sets the parameters of the CRF to represent the relationship between the observed features and the unobserved state. Different CRF architectures can allow you to add dependencies between multiple hidden states.

Comment: Thanks David Mimno for responding to my question. I really appreciate your help.
I will try to elaborate on my question here. The feature functions in a CRF model can depend on both input (observed) sequence and output (hidden) label `f(x, y_t)`. I would like to include "label-observation", "node-observation" features in my model. Those feature functions can be expressed as `f(x,y_t) = I(y_t=y_t') * g(x)` (where `I(y_t=y_t')` is an indicator function that equals 1 when y_t = y_t' and `g(x)` depends solely on x). .....(To be continued)

Comment: As per my understanding, we have to provide the values of all feature functions to mallet (upfront). But, the value of these features (label-observation and node-observation) depends on the output (hidden) sequence that is being considered. During inference, as the model explores all possible output sequences, the values of these feature functions will change. Can you point me towards how to include such type of features in mallet.

Comment: @user:6287504 : Let me know if my comments are still not clear ; Thanks again